# How to use the underline character in English?

Tags: punctuation, emphasis, orthography

I've been learning English for 5 years, but I don't understand when or how to use underline character (_) in English.
Please can you help me explain it to me?

Example about hyphen, I read [here](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/hyphen) and then I understood it. But underline I can't.

Comment: I don't understand how to use it in Russian. Are there any specific rules? I thought one just uses it when they feel like it.

Comment: Are you sure? Maybe underline have another meaning in English. :)

Comment: The underscore character usually substitutes for the space character in cases where the latter one just can’t be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An underline is a way of emphasizing or distinguishing words from others within a sentence.  Italics are another way of doing so.  [This article](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/italics.htm) may help you out, so could [this one](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/punctuation/rules-for-underlining.html).

To quote from one of the links: To underscore something in a piece of writing that is particularly important: “books *are not* to be placed on the floor.” The underline gives the word a bit more gravity.  When spoken, the words "are not" would be stressed or emphasized over the other words in the sentence.

I can't figure out how to underline here, but "are not" should be underlined, though italics lends a similar emphasis.

You would use it similarly to when you might stress a word in a sentence because it is more important.

For the underscore however, it iss primarily used in programming in places which a space is not allowed (or inconvenient, like a file name).  It's origin is the typewriter, where it was used to underline words, see [here](http://www.really-learn-english.com/underscore-sign.html)

Comment: I'm sorry, my question isn't clearly.
this underline is one character, It is same as hyphen character, it isn't underline same as "This article" of you. Example: instead of I write "The name", I'll write "The_name". :)

Comment: That would be the underscore character, my apologies for not seeing that.

Comment: What is the difference between the meaning of underline and underscore? At this time, I think they have same meaning. :)

Comment: An underscore isn't generally used other than for creating blank spaces like this: ______, or in an email address where you want a space but can't put one, such as joe_smith@example.com.  An underline is used to emphasize a word or words like italics would.  If you've ever noticed while you speak, you might say a word louder than others in a sentence because it is more important.  An underline is the visual representation of an emphasized word or phrase.

Comment: Oh, I don't see editing from your post. Thank u so much about your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The underline (or underscore—the two terms mean the same thing) is not used as a separate character in ordinary written English. It is only used beneath characters to indicate emphasis. That's why it's called an **under**line.

In programming contexts, however, it is often used to replace an orthographic space, as in variable and function names, or your example:

> joe_smith@example.com

This is because most programming languages treat an actual space as the separator between tokens, so you can't have spaces inside a name. For instance, if you have two functions named 'Print Now' and 'Print Later', your compiler will interpret these as commands to 'Print' the (probably non-existent) entities 'Now' and 'Later'.

Consequently, programmers often use the underscore character so the two parts of the name are bound together for the compiler but separated for the human reader: 'Print_Now' and 'Print_Later'.

"Camel case" is another device for accomplishing the same thing: 'PrintNow' and 'PrintLater'.

Comment: (y), Maybe you are programmer. In case, I understand why we use _ for functions name. :D